# Page Edit Mode for Lists in SharePoint 2016

Tags: list-view, 2016

We recently upgraded to SharePoint 2016 (way late). Before our upgrade, when we were in a list view, we used the Page ribbon to edit the page, then we would Edit Web Part, and in the resulting dialog, under the Advanced section, we would assign a target audience. This was how we accomplished view-level permissions in SharePoint 2013.

***Now that we have upgraded to SharePoint 2016, when we are in a list view, we no longer have the Page ribbon. Is there some setting we have missed that would give us this ribbon back? Or has this feature been phased out?***

After perusing web forums, it looks like I could create a new page, add a web part that links to a given list view, and then target the audience for that web part. However, I would rather not create what are essentially duplicate pages, if there is a way I can get that Page ribbon back on the original list view itself.

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're on the page containing the List, you can go to the Gear icon in the upper right -> Edit Page. This will allow you to modify the page the List resides on.

Comment: Good lord that was easy :D Thank you!